# how to setup jaeger backend when services are running in different hosts?

Tags: jaeger

I'm following this tutorial: https://github.com/yurishkuro/opentracing-tutorial/tree/master/java/src/main/java/lesson03. What need to be set so that services running in different hosts can send the data to the same backend?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Run Jaeger agent (or OpenTelemetry Collector) on each host that runs your applications and let the agent forward trace data to a central Jaeger collector. The Jaeger client can continue emitting data via UDP port in this case.
2. Configure the Jaeger client with an HTTP endpoint of the Jaeger collector.

For (2), you can pass the environment variable to you applications:

```
JAEGER_ENDPOINT=http://jaeger-collector:14268/api/traces
```

Additional references:

- https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/latest/client-features/
- https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-java/tree/master/jaeger-core

Comment: For (2), if you use OpenTelemetry Python SDK, the envvar would be [`OTEL_EXPORTER_JAEGER_ENDPOINT`](https://opentelemetry-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sdk/environment_variables.html#envvar-OTEL_EXPORTER_JAEGER_ENDPOINT) instead.

Comment: If you use OpenTelemetry SDK it's best to use OTLP exporter, not the Jaeger format.